# How to read the kernel log messages in c?

Tags: c, linux, logging, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to develop a C function that the return the last 5 messages of the kernel log (dmesg).

How I can do that?

Comment: in *nix OSs' the `tail` utility already is written in C and displays the last 'x' lines of any file.  (the 'x' can be set via a parameter to the function.)   You could download the source and modify it for your needs,.

Comment: you would get a lot better answers if you tried to implement this yourself and then posted your code and related details, if it did not work as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `klogctl`.  An example of usage is in the busybox source for [dmesg.c](http://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/util-linux/dmesg.c).